# React native won't start

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm new to React Native. I used the [React Native Firebase starter kit](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter) and followed all the steps, but as soon as I want to start, it gets stuck at this screen:
[image]
Has anyone experienced this or know how to fix this?

UPDATE: When I run `npm run iOS` I get the following error:
[image]

Content of `Package.json`

```
{
  "name": "ReactNativeStarter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-install": "2.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "^6.0.1",
    "jest": "^23.4.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "replace-in-file": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "rename": "node ./bin/rename.js",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fbjs": "^0.8.17",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^4.3.6"
  }
}
```

Content of `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-jsx-source"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is the packager. When it first start and finish loading it would look like that. What about the emulator/ device? Does it show the same thing like the one in their image?

Comment: Have you run react-native run-ios in another terminal?

Comment: I've Updated the question @rabbit87

Comment: I've Updated the question @LaurieWilliams

Comment: This is the same error message as the one you get if try to use React Native 0.56 with Babel plugins that are not compatible with Babel 7. Can you post the contents of your project's `package.json` and `.babelrc`?

Comment: It seems that something is misconfigured. Which version of RN are you running?

Comment: Updated @fagerbua

Comment: Version: "react-native": "^0.56.0" @LaurieWilliams

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also co
py and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Babel needs to be upgraded.

> When upgrading to 0.56, make sure to bump your babel-preset-react-native package.json dependency to ^5.0.1 or newer.

However, you are using babel-preset-react-native-stage-0 which does not seem to support React Native 0.56.0. See https://github.com/skevy/babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/issues/8

My advice would be to try using babel-preset-react-native until a fix for babel-preset-react-native-stage-0 is released.

Comment: Changed it, but now getting the: bundling failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined error, which comes from the "transform-react-jsx-source" plugin

Comment: Remove transform-react-jsx-source" {
  ...
   "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-display-name",
        "transform-react-jsx-source", // <1----
        "transform-react-jsx-self"
      ]
    },
  ...
}
See https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4155

Comment: You may also need to ensure you have version 5 of `babel-preset-react-native` installed. Earlier versions don't seem to work with React Native 0.56.